# HTML/PHP Form Submitting to 404 Eorror

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

SO. I work on this Wordpress site. Which believe me is SO annoying. So I have this huge mass of code which is a combo of PHP and HTML. Everything appears just fine until the form is submitted. When the page refreshes it loads to the same page (with the same exact URL) but with a 404 Error.

```
<center>
  <code>
    [insert_php]
      // Info to connect to the Wishlist database
      $servername = "eggcavity.com";
      $dbusername = "******";
      $password = "*******";
      $dbname = "EggcavityTravelIndex";

      try {
        // To connect to the database please
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') ' . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Get current user's username
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $username = $current_user->user_login;
        $allowed_roles = array('moderator', 'administrator');

        if ($username == "") {
          // If person is not logged in
          echo "Please login to see if you have moderator privileges.";
        } else if (array_intersect($allowed_roles, $current_user->roles )) {
          // If person is logged in and has moderator privileges, show the page

          $page = 1;

          if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != ""){
            $page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
          }

          if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $ids = $_POST['ids'];
            $theCount = 0;

            // Prepare and bind the udpate statement
            $sql2 = "UPDATE Travels SET Name = ?, Picture = ?, Price = ?, " .
              "Description = ?, Rarity = ?, Status = ? WHERE ID = ?";
            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
            $stmt2->bind_param('ssssssi', $name, $picture, $price, $description, $rarity, $status, $id);

            foreach($ids as $id){
              $namecode = $id . "name";
              $picturecode = $id . "picture";
              $pricecode = $id . "price";
              $raritycode = $id . "rarity";
              $descriptioncode = $id . "description";
              $statuscode = $id . "status";
              $name = $_POST[$namecode];
              $picture = $_POST[$picturecode];
              $price = $_POST[$pricecode];
              $rarity = $_POST[$raritycode];
              $description = $_POST[$descriptioncode];
              $status = $_POST[$statuscode];
              $stmt2->execute();
            }

            if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
              $delete=!empty( $_POST['delete'] ) ? $_POST['delete'] : false;
                if($delete && !is_array($delete) ){
                  $delete=explode(',',$delete);
                }

                foreach($delete as $id){
                  $sql = "DELETE FROM Travels WHERE ID = ?";
                  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
                  $stmt->execute();
                  $theCount++;
                }
              }
              echo "<font size='3'>The travel database has been updated, and " . $theCount . 
                " travels(s) has/have been removed.";
            } else {
              // Just display the form
              $start = 0;
              $stop = 100;
              if ($page == "2") {
                $start = 100;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "3") {
                $start = 200;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "4") {
                $start = 300;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "5") {
                $start = 400;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "6") {
                $start = 500;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "7") {
                $start = 600;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "8") {
                $start = 700;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "9") {
                $start = 800;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "10") {
                $start = 900;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "11") {
                $start = 1000;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "12") {
                $start = 1100;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "13") {
                $start = 1200;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "14") {
                $start = 1300;
                $stop = 100;
              } else if ($page == "15") {
                $start = 1400;
                $stop = 100;
              }
              $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Travels LIMIT ' . $start . ',' . $stop;
              $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              $sql11 = 'SELECT * FROM Travels';
              $result11 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
              $numtravels = mysqli_num_rows($result11);
              if ($numtravels > 0) {
                $numpages = ceil($numtravels / 100);
                $cnt = 1;
                echo 'Pages: ';
                while ($cnt <= $numpages){
                  echo '<a style="border-style:solid;border-radius:5px;border-width:1px;padding:2px;" href="?' . $cnt . '">' 
                    . $cnt . '</a> ';
                  $cnt++;
                }
                echo '<br><br>';
                $begin = $start + 1;
                $end = $begin + 99;
                echo '<form method="POST"><table style="border-collapse: collapse";>' .
                  'Travels ' . $begin . ' to ' . $end;

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $name = $row["Name"];
                  $id = $row["ID"];
                  $picture = $row["Picture"];
                  $price = $row["Price"];
                  $rarity= $row["Rarity"];
                  $description = $row["Description"];
                  $status= $row["Status"];
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><br><img src="' . $picture . '"></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' .
                    '<strong>Name: </strong><input type="text" name="' . $id . 'name" value="' . $name . '"></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' .
                    '<strong>Image URL: </strong><input type="text" name="' . $id . 'picture" value="' . $picture . '"></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' .
                    '<strong>Price: </strong><input type="text" name="' . $id . 'price" value="' . $price . '"></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' .
                    '<strong>Rarity: </strong><input type="text" name="' . $id . 'rarity" value="' . $rarity . '"></td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
                  echo '<td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' .
                    '<strong>Description: </strong><br><input style="width:300px" type="text" name="' . $id . 'description" value="' . $description . '"></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><strong>Status: </strong><br><select name="' . $id . 'status">' .
                    '<option value ="' . $status . '" selected>' . $status . '</option>';
                  if ($status == "Available") {
                    echo '<option value ="Retired">Retired</option>';
                  } else if ($status == "Retired") {
                    echo '<option value ="Available">Available</option>';
                  } else if ($status == "") {
                    echo '<option value ="Retired">Retired</option>';
                    echo '<option value ="Available">Available</option>';
                  }
                  echo '</select></td>';
                  echo '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' . '<strong>Delete</strong><br>' . 
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="' . $id . '"></td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
                }
              echo '</table><br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update">' .
                '</form><br><br>';
            } else {
              echo "<br>There are no travels in the database.";
            }
          }

        } else {
          // If person is logged in but does not have mod privileges
          echo "Sorry, you're not a moderator!";
        }

      } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
      }
      // Close the connection to the database
      $conn->close();
    [/insert_php]
  </code>
</center>
```

[image: Here is a picture of the form]
This is the form

[image: And a picture after submitting the form]
And this is the page after submission.

The code is SO similar to a page that I do have working. As shown here:

```
<center>
  <code>
    [insert_php]
      // Info to connect to the Wishlist database
      $servername = "eggcavity.com";
      $dbusername = "********";
      $password = "*******";
      $dbname = "EggcavityTravelIndex";

      try {
        // To connect to the database please
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') ' . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Get current user's username
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $username = $current_user->user_login;

        if ($username == ""){
          echo "Please login to use wishlist feature.";
        } else {

        echo "<font size ='3'><br>Please click <strong>" .
          "<a href = 'http://eggcavity.com/add-wishlist'>here</a></strong>" .
          " to add creatures to your wishlist.<br><br>Please click <strong>" .
          "<a href='http://eggcavity.com/wishlists'>here</a></strong> to view your wishlist.<br>" .
          "<br>At the moment when you enter notes you cannot view them on the edit page." .
          "<br>Please go to the view wishlist page to see your notes.<br><br></font>";

        $page = 1;
        if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != ""){
          $page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          $ids = $_POST['ids'];
          $theCount = 0;

          // Prepare and bind the udpate statement
          $sql2 = "UPDATE Wishlists SET Picture = ?, Stage = ?, Gender = ?, " .
            "Frozen = ?, Notes= ? WHERE ID = ?";
          $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
          $stmt2->bind_param('sssssi', $picture, $stage, $gender, $frozen, $notes, $id);

          foreach($ids as $id){
            $stagecode = $id . "stage";
            $gendercode = $id . "gender";
            $frozencode = $id . "frozen";
            $notescode = $id . "notes";
            $namecode = $id . "creature";
            $stage = $_POST[$stagecode];
            $Stage = $stage;
            $gender = $_POST[$gendercode];
            $frozen = $_POST[$frozencode];
            $notes = $_POST[$notescode];
            $name = $_POST[$namecode];
            $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM Creatures WHERE Name = "' . $name . '"';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $picture = $row["$stage"];
            $stmt2->execute();
          }

          if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $delete=!empty( $_POST['delete'] ) ? $_POST['delete'] : false;
              if($delete && !is_array($delete) ){
                $delete=explode(',',$delete);
              }

              foreach($delete as $id){
                $sql = "DELETE FROM Wishlists WHERE ID = ?";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $theCount++;
              }
            }
            echo "<font size='3'>Your wishlist has been updated, and " . $theCount . 
              " creature(s) has/have been removed from your wishlist.<br><br>Please click <u>" .
              "<strong><a href='http://eggcavity.com/edit-wishlist'>here</a></u></strong>" .
              " to return to the edit page.</href><br><br>";
          } else {
            // Just display the form
            $start = 0;
            $stop = 100;
            if ($page == "2") {
              $start = 100;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "3") {
              $start = 200;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "4") {
              $start = 300;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "5") {
              $start = 400;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "6") {
              $start = 500;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "7") {
              $start = 600;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "8") {
              $start = 700;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "9") {
              $start = 800;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "10") {
              $start = 900;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "11") {
              $start = 1000;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "12") {
              $start = 1100;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "13") {
              $start = 1200;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "14") {
              $start = 1300;
              $stop = 100;
            } else if ($page == "15") {
              $start = 1400;
              $stop = 100;
            }
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Wishlists WHERE Username = "' . $username .
              '" ORDER BY Creature LIMIT ' . $start . ',' . $stop;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $sql11 = 'SELECT * FROM Wishlists WHERE Username = "' . $username . '"';
            $result11 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
            $numcreatures = mysqli_num_rows($result11);
            if ($numcreatures > 0) {
              $numpages = ceil($numcreatures / 100);
              $cnt = 1;
              echo 'Pages: ';
              while ($cnt <= $numpages){
                echo '<a style="border-style:solid;border-radius:5px;border-width:1px;padding:2px;" href="?' . $cnt . '">' 
                  . $cnt . '</a> ';
                $cnt++;
              }
              echo '<br><br>';
              $begin = $start + 1;
              $end = $begin + 99;
              echo '<form method="POST"><table style="border-collapse: collapse";><strong>' .
                'Creatures ' . $begin . ' to ' . $end .
                '<tr>' .
                  '<td>' . $numcreatures . ' creatures</td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Creature</td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Stage</td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Gender</td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">Frozen</td>' .
                '</tr></strong>';

              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $creature = $row["Creature"];
                $id = $row["ID"];
                $picture = $row["Picture"];
                $stage = $row["Stage"];
                $sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM Creatures WHERE Name = "' . $creature . '"';
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
                $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
                echo '<input name="ids[]" type="hidden" value="' . $id . '">' .
                  '<input name="' . $id . 'creature" type="hidden" value="' . $creature . '">' .
                  '<tr>' .
                    '<td rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><img src="' . 
                      $picture . '"></td>' .
                    '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' . $creature . '</td>' .
                    '<td style"border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 
                      'stage">' .
                      '<option value ="' . $stage . '" selected>' . $stage . '</option>' . 
                      '<option value = "Stage1">Stage1(Egg)</option>' .
                      '<option value = "Stage2">Stage2</option>';

                if ($row2["Stage3"] != "") {
                  echo '<option value = "Stage3">Stage3</option>';
                }

                if ($row2["Stage4"] != "") {
                  echo '<option value = "Stage4">Stage4</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 
                    'gender">' .
                    '<option value ="' . $row["Gender"]. '" selected>' . $row["Gender"] . '</option>' . 
                    '<option value = "Unspecified">Unspecified</option>' .
                    '<option value = "Female">Female</option>' .
                    '<option value = "Male">Male</option>' . 
                  '</select></td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;"><select name="' . $id . 
                    'frozen">' .
                    '<option value ="' . $row["Frozen"] . '" selected>' . $row["Frozen"] . '</option>' . 
                    '<option value="Unspecified">Unspecified</option>' .
                    '<option value="Yes">Yes</option>' .
                    '<option value="No">No</option>' .
                  '</select></td>' .
                '</tr>' .
                '<tr>' .
                  '<td  style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;" colspan="3">Notes: ' . 
                    '<input type="text" name="' . $id . 
                    'notes" value="' . $row["Notes"] .'"></td>' .
                  '<td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:center;">' . 'Delete<br>' . 
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]"
                    value="' . $id . '"></td>' .
                '</tr>';
              }
              echo '</table><br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update">' .
                '</form><br><br>';
            } else {
              echo "<br>You have no creatures in your wishlist.";
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
        throw $e; 
      } 

      // Close the connection to the database
      $conn->close();
    [/insert_php]
  </code>
</center>
```

If you have any ideas what could be causing this please help!

Comment: Now that you've posted your db username/password publicly, you should change them.

Comment: You've got some trickery going on. Start looking in apache, php, and wordpress error logs for answers.

Comment: How does the form know where to POST? Just in case make sure you have an action specifying PHP_SELF since you want to the page to post there.

Comment: @cosmoonot By default forms post to themselves.

Comment: You're very right. I'm so used to specifying it.

Comment: @mkaatman  yes it is definetly trickery haha. I have checked error logs and I cannot find anything that is hinting towards anything usefull

Comment: Start eliminating from the pages until it stops breaking. Eliminate all the php and db calls and post a simple HTML form and see if the behavior changes and then start adding pieces back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your page saved and published?

If not, that might be the issue why it's saying that page is not found.

Also, there is a better way to handle page number generation (or pagination) than the long if else statements you have written.

Please go over this: http://code.runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms

It would also be wise to have a custom Wordpress plugin where you would have all this logic instead of pages since anyone with Wordpress admin access would be able to change the code and you certainly wouldn't want that.

Comment: Deff saved and published. I will look through that. But I am just hoping to get this working first (: I have never dabbled in the plugins so maybe I'll test the waters